# PHP simple BB code - ending the formatting

Tags: php, replace, bbcode

I am trying to create a simple BB code like script in PHP for my forum. The problem is, I am not sure how to stop a user posting something like this..

```
[b] Hahah
[b] Will make all of your text
[b] on this page bold
```

This would display (because I'm replacing words)

```
<strong> Hahah
<strong> Will make all of your text
<strong> on this page bold
```

What would be a good way to prevent this and end the tags at the bottom of the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing BBCode by HTML is actually not as easy as it seems. Just using `str_replace()` will never be good enough. Because, as you said, people can just only place the open tag and this way, change your layout. A popular 'solution' is to use `preg_replace()` instead, with a regular expression that matches both the open and close tag. That, however, is quite unsafe with BBCode tags like `[url]` (you can insert JavaScript in those URL tags).

However, there are some libraries out there that are very good in replacing BBCode. [StringParser_BBCode](http://www.christian-seiler.de/projekte/php/bbcode/index_en.html) is one of those. Those libraries do a little more than just replacing. For example, they will usually prevent malformed BBCode like `[b][i]foo[/b][i]` to turn into `<strong><em>foo</strong></em>` (which is malformed HTML). And also, they can do a lot more on preventing XSS injections.

Comment: Thank-you! I was searching for a simpler class for this, after seeing a BB code library which just seemed more than I needed.

Comment: In my experience, just a 'simple class' is definitely not enough for BBCode. I really recommend using a library, because of the problems with more simple solutions.

Comment: Yeah, thing is though I wasn't looking for a full suite of BB codes, but just a few like bold text, italic text and coloured text.